# click and touchend not getting fired on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

on a page in my website, I have chart. It is in essence an svg image that represents a pie chart, with 3 html text items as labels. I want to click on those, change the text in the middle of the piechart and then scroll down the page. Desktop works fine, but there the text changes on hover. However, when I'm testing on my phone, my code for the mobile version doesn't work. Below is the code I currently have:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    console.log( "inside window load" );
   var linksies = jQuery(".home-chart")[0].children[1].children[0].children[3].children;
   var handler = function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log( "inside click event" );
       var newtext = phrtext;
       jQuery("#chartTitle").text(newtext);
       //'home-'+textie
       var divid = "#" + datatarget;
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: jQuery(divid).offset().top
       }, 3000);
   };
   for (var j=0;j<linksies.length;j++)
   {
        linksies[j].onclick = handler;
        linksies[j].ontouchend = handler;
   }
});
```

The code inside the handler isn't completely correct, but I don't even get inside that function. "linksies" is an array that holds the 3 text objects. I don't get any errors when assigning the handler function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Alert `linksies.length` and check...

Comment: When I debug, I get inside that for loop and I see the onclick function being filled in.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JulieVe/v3bfj3dw/

Comment: you will have to test on a mobile device, because the google emulator does get into the handler function

Comment: I'll put the links for the external resources below:

- https://aquaterratest.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-charts/js/Chart.min.js?ver=4.4.2

- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js

- https://aquaterratest.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-charts//js/functions.js?ver=4.4.2

Comment: - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css

- https://aquaterratest.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/desktop.css?ver=2

- https://aquaterratest.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/style.css?ver=3.4.19

- https://aquaterratest.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/mobile.css

Comment: Provided fiddle does not work..Kindly provide working fiddle..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JulieVe/v3bfj3dw/

it should work, above are the used resources in case they are missing from the fiddle

Comment: http://aquaterratest.azurewebsites.net/ this is the website where the code is used